# Char vector from JNI to Java

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a vector of char in my C++ code. How can I return it to Java through JNI? What analogous data type should I use for this in Java?

Comment: You can use a `Vector` or better, an `ArrayList`

Comment: How can I return vector<char> variable to Java from c++?

Comment: Yes but... don't. I'd suggest using `ArrayList<Integer>` instead. But yes you can. The `sizeof(char)` isn't the same below the hood (in C) and above (in Java)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214707/properly-returning-a-hardcoded-byte-from-jni-to-java) to get an idea how to return values from JNI to Java. And I guess you can use a bytearray as well.

Comment: "What analogous data type should I use for this in Java?": we can't really answer that for you but it is the crux of the problem. What type of data is in your vector, integers or characters? If integers, what range? If characters, which character set and encoding? Or, would an array of bytes do? You must have some use case on the Java side.

Comment: I have a vector of chars as UTF-8.

Comment: And on the Java side, you want a `string`? Or what? Please [edit] your question with some Java client code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is surprisingly non-trivial: a `char` in C++ has its `sizeof` standardised at 1, could be an `unsigned` or `signed` type and, if it's the latter, it could be 2's or 1's complement although 1's complement is removed from C++14 onwards!

The Java `char` is a 16 bit `unsigned`.

I think the best way to convert your `char` vector is to use one of the Java byte array classes.